# How big a function argument size before it's more efficient to pass by reference or pointer?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

I've heard it said that passing by reference or pointer can be more efficient because it avoids a copy. I'm assuming this obviously doesn't apply for small arguments, for example doubles. Sometimes I deal with vec3 and vec4s which might be about 32 bytes big. I have a habit of passing by reference because I have this idea in mind, but I'm wondering if it's actually worth doing. IT makes sense that if copies are avoided it's faster, but how big would the argument generally need to be to gain anything? Are we talking about 8 bytes, 32 bytes? Or much bigger?

I'm not sure how passing by reference or pointer actually works under the hood anyway. For example is it possible it's actually slower with a reference because the memory address is used to retrieve the information when a simple copy would mean the object is available immediately.

Comment: Depends on the machine architecture I'd say. On a 64 bit architecture it's likely to be more efficient to use references over 64 bits of memory used as data.

Comment: An object with only a single byte in size could be prohibitively expensive to copy, while an object of thousands of bytes in size could be very cheap. It all depends on how the copying is done, and what the objects copy-constructor does. There's really no straight answer unless you specify an explicit object and shows us its type and possible copy-constructor (if not the default).

Comment: If you want to order a meal. Will you give the delivery guy your address or your House?.

Comment: If `uintmax_t` or smaller, pass by value.  if pointer, pass by value, If numeric (up to complex long  double), pass by value.  If a `struct/union`, pass by ref.

Comment: I am surprised that this question have been such down-voted: this seems a legitimate question I asked myself several times already. I am pretty sure that the answer is "it all depends", but I tend to conclude as AKL that, as a rough estimate, the threshold is above 16 bytes on a 64-bit processor. BTW, the mentioned "duplicate" question is much more general and not about performance.

Comment: Profile, profile, profile.  On my machine, it seems the break even point is between 256 bytes and 512 bytes.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that accessing a pointer and copying an `int` value takes same amount of processors time, and if the following test is true:

```
std::is_trivially_copy_constructible<type>::value == true
```

, then the formula for passing by reference could be the following:

```
sizeof(type) > 2 * sizeof(type*)
```

where `type` is type of the argument to the function.

Comment: Why are you making this assumption?

Comment: But sizeof a type does not tell anything about how complex and time consuming algorithms its copy constructror runs.

Comment: @Eugene I am not assuming, I said if that is  true then this

Comment: @ÖöTiib you are right , but I assumed that type is using a default copy constructor! I will update my answer

Comment: @AKL Even a default constructors RT complexity cannot be known in advance for every type. You need to decide case by case what's more efficient (by means of performance vs stack memory consumpiton).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ how about types which their members also have default copy constructors?

Comment: @AKL Sure, and these member types in the members also have default constructors aso.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes that is  exactly what I mean, I think they are called trivial types or something like that

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ don't you agree that at least in those case I am right?

Comment: @AKL Let's agree we disagree that what you provided in your answer is a good rule of thumb.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I updated my answer, please take a look!

Comment: This is clearly a rule of thumb, but I ended up having the same, passing notably pairs of  `double` (like a geographical coordinate) by value, but bigger values by reference (on 64-bit CPU).